# Invalid request handling in OData

Tags: c#, odata

Im writing an OData webservice with C# and I need some advice on how to handle invalid requests? An example of an error would be if a customer requested a service on an item they no longer own. I would idealy like to report back to the customer exactly why it is invalid as there are multiple possible reasons.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using FaultContracts as part of the OperationContract.  You can define them just like DataContracts, and handle exceptions just like a custom exception.

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ItemNotOwned))]
Item GetItem(int ItemId);
```

You would define ItemNotOwned as a seperate contract definition.

Check it out on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733841.aspx#Y323

Comment: Looks like its just for SOAP. Im using REST

Comment: Oh, yep, faults are just SOAP. If you are using HttpClient for REST then normal exceptions will be serialized.  You'll need to unwind them on the other end of the wire yourself, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw an exception with the message containing that information. The exception will be serialized to the response sent to the client. If you don't care about the response status code, any exception will do and the client will recieve 500 (Internal Server Error). If you want a specific status code throw an instance of DataServiceException.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using QueryInterceptors and ChangeInterceptors

http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/24/wcf-rest-service-with-odata-and-entity-framework-with-client-context-custom-operations-and-operation-interceptors/