# Best practices for error handling in a WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

What's the best practice to throw exceptions from Wcf Data Service and to catch them from .net client?

Comment: Someone telling how to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508003/invalid-request-handling-in-odata

Answer (score 2):

In general I'm not sure there are a lot of best practices, but here are a couple of thoughts that might help.

1. By default WCF Data Services will not transmit exception detail to the client. This is because we believe services should be secure by default. Transmitting exception detail could result in unintentional information disclosure. To turn detailed exception transmission on, you'll need to add the `ServiceBehavior` attribute to your service and set `UseVerboseErrors` to true:

```
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Scratch.Web
{
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class ScratchService : DataService<ScratchEntityFrameworkContext>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

1. If you throw exceptions on the server side, only the message is functionally transmitted to the client, so make sure the exception message contains the content you want to show up on the client.
2. Other than that, just follow the other best practices for exception handling on the client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx.